# OpenJFX Maven archetype does not exist?

Tags: java, maven, javafx, openjfx

I tried to create a JavaFX maven project following the [official doc](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/) (chapter IntelliJ with maven, non modular project). I replaced as outlined the archtype artififact id as : `javafx-archetype-simple`  but when I try to create a project using the archtype, I still get the following error :

> Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.1.1:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: The desired archetype does not exist (org.openjfx:maven-archetype-quickstart:0.0.1)

Any clue of what I did wrong ?

Comment: There are a lot of different steps in the doc. Which route did you take?

Comment: Yes sorry, I edited to indicate what chapter I took

Comment: Look at https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/openjfx/javafx-maven-archetypes/0.0.1/. There is no JAR in the repository. How did you import it?

Comment: I added the coordinates in IntelliJ archetypes menu

Comment: You missed the part that says `Select the archetype artifactId, between javafx-archetype-fxml or javafx-archetype-simple, based on the use of FXML or not in your project.`

Comment: @JoséPereda Thank you for your answer it was indeed the case, I updated my post according to your advice but it still doesn't work.

Comment: You can even try version 0.0.5, it should be available: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/openjfx/javafx-archetype-simple/0.0.5/ (even 0.0.1 should work).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending a lot of time on this, I realized that I wasn't indicating "javafx-version" in the properties tab.

I set that property to 12 and it worked for me. Here's a pic.

[image: screenshot of the menu]

Also, as @JosePereda noted, make sure to choose the correct archetypeArtifactId